# An example on how to use Agda Standard Library monoid solver

Tags: agda

I'm developing a code with a lot of boring list concatenation equalities, so I do want to use a monoid solver. I know that module Algebra.Monoid-solver implements a monoid solver, but I do not find any example on how to use it.

Can someone provide a quick example using the stdlib monoid solver ?

Best,

Comment: There are examples of the *ring* solver being used in [Data.Digit](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Digit.html#809) and [Data.DivMod](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Nat.DivMod.html#2545). The Monoid one is used in the same fashion (you need to produce a representation of both sides).

Comment: I'll check you to use the ring solver and adapt the idea to the monoid one. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick example:

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.List
open import Data.List.Properties
open List-solver renaming (nil to :[]; _⊕_ to _:++_; _⊜_ to _:≡_)

assoc : {A : Set} (xs ys zs : List A) -> xs ++ (ys ++ zs) ≡ (xs ++ ys) ++ zs
assoc = solve 3 (λ xs ys zs -> xs :++ (ys :++ zs) :≡ (xs :++ ys) :++ zs) refl
```

Agda can partially infer the type signature:

```
assoc : {A : Set} (xs ys zs : List A) -> _
assoc = solve 3 (λ xs ys zs -> xs :++ (ys :++ zs) :≡ (xs :++ ys) :++ zs) refl
```

There are also at least two front-ends for the ring solver: [1](https://github.com/xplat/agda-tactics/blob/master/Tactics/Nat/Semiring.agda) and [2](https://github.com/wjzz/Agda-reflection-for-semiring-solver), you can write a front-end for the monoid solver in a similar way.

Have you considered using difference lists, which have definitional associativity?

Check [this](https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2011/003420.html) thread also.